# Periodically Querying Postgresql and Visualize it On Dashboard

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, tableau-api, prometheus

Here is the case, i want to visualize a query result of data taken periodically into dashboard (like `grafana` or `kibana`), the problem is I don't know which technology stack to use, should I use ELK stack, Prometheus + Grafana, or using Tableau, the requirements are:

1. First, it has support for multiple (hundreds) of database server as data source, currently I use Postgresql.
2. Second, it has support for running **one query to all database instance** and collect the result into one centralized server to be then displayed on dashboard.
3. Third, it has support for **period/schedule** set up (cron-like scheduler) for managing how often data should be queried from all database servers.
4. Fourth, it has support for alerting/notification system, where i can use existing platform library without much code needed.
5. Fifth, it has to be opensource project, with good reputation and quite large community support.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your objective with ELK Stack. In Kibana, you will see basic Dashboard. If you want more detail Dashboard view, then you can integrate Elastic Search with Grafana as well using Lucene query.Below links will help you:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-schedule-logstash-every-second-for-jdbc-input-plugin/27393/11

https://grafana.com/blog/2016/03/09/how-to-effectively-use-the-elasticsearch-data-source-in-grafana-and-solutions-to-common-pitfalls/#lucene